# convert date format with utc

Tags: php, date

I want to convert date format from  'Wed, 27 01 2016 00:00:00 EST' to '2016-01-27'.I got wrong value '1970-01-01'

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki"); 
$var='Wed, 25 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT';
echo $d=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($var));
//DATE_RFC2822
?>
```

Comment: What is the error(or) result you got?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the datetime string cannot be recognised automatically. You need to specify format of input:

```
echo date_create_from_format(
    'D, d m Y H:i:s e',  // <== input format  
    'Wed, 27 01 2016 00:00:00 EST'  // <== your string
)->format("Y-m-d")  // <== output format
```

More formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php